# How to distinguish between iOS and Mac OS in Shell Script

Tags: ios, bash, macos, shell, sh

I have tried below code

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
fi
```

Above code is not differentiating between iOS and Mac OS, iOS and Mac both fall under the same condition.

Comment: What would `uname -a` show in both cases?

Comment: "Darwin" in both cases

Comment: I don't have a way to test on iOS, but try `sw_vers -productName` -- on macOS, it prints "Mac OS X" or "macOS" (depending on the version).

Comment: @AbhishekSinha : Can't be. In this case, you forgot the `-a` option.

Comment: In `bash`, you have `$MACHTYPE` and `$HOSTTYPE` which define the underlying architecture (amd, arm, ...). If you have access to `sysctl` on both side, the `hw.machine` kernel state will give the following info eg: `OSX=>x86_64`, `iOS=>iPhoneX.Y` or `iPadX.Y` with `X.Y` the iPhone/iPad version number. Finally, `uname -m` gives the same info (ie machine).